# WP8 Push notification channel name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using the following code in my page load event and getting the exception on channel name.

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

// The name of our push channel.
string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";
pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WMAppManifest, you will need to add ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION capability.

```
<Capabilities>
      ......
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
</Capabilities>
```